# OpenCV: Shift/Align face image relative to reference Image (Image Registration)

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, translate, face-recognition

I am new to OpenCV2 and working on a project in emotion recognition and would like to align a facial image in relation to a reference facial image. I would like to get the image translation working before moving to rotation. Current idea is to run a search within a limited range on both x and y coordinates and use the sum of squared differences as error metric to select the optimal x/y parameters to align the image. I'm using the OpenCV face_cascade function to detect the face images, all images are resized to a fixed (128x128). Question: Which parameters of the Mat image do I need to modify to shift the image in a positive/negative direction on both x and y axis? I believe setImageROI is no longer supported by Mat datatypes? I have the ROIs for both faces available however I am unsure how to use them.

```
void alignImage(vector<Rect> faceROIstore, vector<Mat> faceIMGstore)
{
  Mat refimg = faceIMGstore[1]; //reference image
  Mat dispimg = faceIMGstore[52]; // "displaced" version of reference image
  //Rect refROI = faceROIstore[1]; //Bounding box for face in reference image
  //Rect dispROI = faceROIstore[52]; //Bounding box for face in displaced image
  Mat aligned;

  matchTemplate(dispimg, refimg, aligned, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
  imshow("Aligned image", aligned);
}
```

The idea for this approach is based on [Image Alignment Tutorial by Richard Szeliski](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70092/tr-2004-92.pdf) Working on Windows with OpenCV 2.4. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: hi abhischek!I am having the same problem as you..could you please guide me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296058/align-profile-face-image-with-its-frontal-face-image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Mat` does support ROI. (But it does not support COI - channel-of-interest.)

To apply ROI you can use `operator()` or special constructor:

```
Mat refimgROI  = faceIMGstore[1](faceROIstore[1]); //reference image ROI
Mat dispimgROI(faceIMGstore[52], faceROIstore[52]); // "displaced" version of reference image ROI
```

And to find the best position inside a displaced image you can utilize [matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#matchtemplate) function.

---

Based on your comments I can suggest the following code which will find the best position of reference patch nearby the second (displaced) patch:

```
Mat ref = faceIMGstore[1](faceROIstore[1]);
Mat disp = faceIMGstore[52](faceROIstore[52]);

disp = disp.adjustROI(5,5,5,5); //allow 5 pixel max adjustment in any direction
if(disp.cols < ref.cols || disp.rows < ref.rows)
    return 0;
Mat map;
cv::matchTemplate( disp, ref, map, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED );

Point  minLoc;
cv::minMaxLoc( map, 0, &minLoc );

Mat adjusted = disp(Rect(minLoc.x, minLoc.y, ref.cols, ref.rows));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have implemented template match now, however when I output the resulting matrix it is displayed as a dot!? aligned.cols is 1 and aligned.rows is 1! It is worth mentioning that both images are the same size however are not exactly the "same" image. refimg is a neutral expression/ dispimg is a smiling expression. Do you think this will still give a match, or is this the issue causing the result matrix to be a dot? Please see updated code

Comment: It is expected to be the dot when images have the same size - it is in documentation. And if your images have the same size then you simply has nothing to align (or I did not get what you are trying to do). Probably you need to add some margin to the displaced image before calling matchTemplate.

Comment: Yes the images have the same size, however the face on the second image is slightly lower than the first, causing the eyes to be misaligned when I output the overlay using addWeighted. Hence I wanted to "push" the second image upwards to align the eye region.

Comment: Thanks, trying to implement the changes. In your expertise do you reckon this will work for aligning different faces as well (male/female)?

Comment: Hi there!interesting post.In the original function void alignImage(vector<Rect> faceROIstore, vector<Mat> faceIMGstore), what are meaning of the parameters?