# Image alignment-matchTemplate

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, alignment

In this post [OpenCV: Shift/Align face image relative to reference Image (Image Registration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888368/opencv-shift-align-face-image-relative-to-reference-image-image-registration), there is a function called

`void alignImage(vector<Rect> faceROIstore, vector<Mat> faceIMGstore)`

Can somebody explain the meaning of the parameters and how these will be used in the code please?

My second question is: can this function be used to align 2 face images of the same person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OpenCV: Shift/Align face image relative to reference Image (Image Registration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888368/opencv-shift-align-face-image-relative-to-reference-image-image-registration), you can easily found that:

- `vector<Rect> faceROIstore` is a vector containing all face ROI regions.
- `vector<Mat> faceIMGstore` is a vector containing all the corresponding face images.

To get the face ROI region of the image, you can do as follows:

```
Mat face_roi = faceIMGstore[i](faceROIstore[i]); // face ROI region of i-th image
```

---

For your second question: Yes, it can be used to align 2 face images no matter the face images are from the same person or two different persons. They works under the same idea.

Comment: ok.When I call this function in my main,what parameters should I pass to the function?

Comment: @Steph `faceIMGstore` can be the images, and `faceROIstore` will be the face rects.

Comment: I will have 2 images in faceIMGstore(input image and template image).As for faceROIstore,I am quite unsure about it.What do you mean by face rects?

Comment: @Steph The `cv::Rect`s where your faces are.

Comment: faceIMGstore is for the original face images and and faceROIstore is for the detected faces found in the original images.Is that right?

Comment: will try aligning a profile face image with its frontal face and see if it works.thanks :)

Comment: I put the same function in my project."return 0" in the function is underlined because the function has type "void" and no instance of overloaded function "minMaxLoc" matches the argument list :s