# Align profile face image with its frontal face image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a profile face:

[image]

and a frontal face image:

[image]

**Output:** aligned profile face with reference to frontal face.

**Idea:** I just need to know which 3 common points I can take,which will be visible on both faces and then use affineTransform and display the aligned profile face

```
      OR any other **simple method** of doing so
```

**development envi.**:c++ and opencv 2.4.2

**what I tried:**

1. haarcascade feature detection(common detection point in both images=eye) ; it wont detect ear in frontal face
2. [OpenCV: Shift/Align face image relative to reference Image (Image Registration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888368/opencv-shift-align-face-image-relative-to-reference-image-image-registration) (I get error message)

Comment: in general, the stitcher should work for all kind of images, if features can be extracted and matched correctly. `estimateTransform` returns a `cv::Status` value, can you check that?

Comment: in the command window,it stops processing the images at "Pairwise matching, time= ". It does not get to estimateTransform

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I corrected it. However,I am not able to continue in the main http://pastebin.com/S2etkzrC

Comment: @Steph, why don't you detect the some facial landmarks (eyes, nose, chin) using STASM or Flandmark detector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159939/2589776) by @bytefish, finding the accurate position of the eyes in a given image is far from trivial. The Haar-cascades for finding the eyes in OpenCV produce too many false positive to be useful, moreover this approach won't be robust to image rotation.

You'll need a robust head pose estimation for aligning face images. Here are two most robust ones (with code available):

- [Gary B. Huang](http://www.janelia.org/people/scientist/gary-huang), [Vidit Jain](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/~vidit/), and [Erik Learned-Miller](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~elm/). *Unsupervised joint alignment of complex images.* International Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV), 2007. [(Project page)](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/congeal_complex.html), [(PDF Online available)](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/congeal_complex.html), [(Source code)](https://bitbucket.org/gbhuang/congealreal)
- [X. Zhu](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu), [D. Ramanan](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan). *Face Detection, Pose Estimation and Landmark Localization in the Wild* Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR) Providence, Rhode Island, June 2012. [(Project page)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/), [(PDF Online available)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/), [(Source code)](https://github.com/wg-perception/PartsBasedDetector)

---

For example, using the method described in the second paper, you will get more robust features like that are shown in the following images. And these robust features will, in turn, ensure to generate more robust face alignment performance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for this @herohuyongtao but I need a simpler methodand it may not necessarily be robust

Answer (score 1):

If you look for something really simple you can treat your mouth as a line on a planar object and calculate the rotation by the amount of line foreshortening. You should never smile though when you take pictures nor when you write your code.

A much cooler approach though would be to map your face as a texture to a predefined 3D model and rotate it until it correlates best with your profile view.

Of course, the right way to do this is to use a set of different head rotations to train a binary classifier that does only pairwise intensity comparisons as in [Lepetit paper](http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_cvpr04.pdf).