# opencv does not detect mouth correctly...!

Tags: opencv

I am trying to extract mouth(lips) from images. What I did is this. I first extract faces from images and tried to detect mouth using haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml. However, It keeps detecting other parts instead detecting mouth from the face. Is there any other way to detect mouth from face images?

Answer (score 0):

To correctly detect mouth regions, you can try more advanced methods like the following one:

- [X. Zhu](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu), [D. Ramanan](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan). *Face Detection, Pose Estimation and Landmark Localization in the Wild* Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR) Providence, Rhode Island, June 2012. [(Project page)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/), [(PDF Online available)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/), [(Source code)](https://github.com/wg-perception/PartsBasedDetector)

Several real examples can be seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438773/2589776).

Answer (score 0):

You can use some facial landmark detector such as Flandmark detector:
http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/

Or STASM:

http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/